# Using if/else within sql query

Tags: php, mysqli, query-optimization

I have a multi language site and are using this to get the language the user uses:

```
$languagestring = array();
$res1 = "SELECT id, text FROM ".$prefix."_language WHERE lang = 'en' ORDER BY id ASC";
if($result1 = $mysqli->query($res1)){ 
    while($row1 = $result1->fetch_object()){
        $langid = $row1->id;

        $res = "SELECT text FROM ".$prefix."_language WHERE fk_id = $langid AND lang = '$language'";
        if($result = $mysqli->query($res)){ 
            $row = $result->fetch_object();
            if(!$row){
                $languagestring[] = $row1->text;
            } else {
                $str = $row->text;
                $languagestring[] = $str;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In this script I first get the default english language and then I check to see if the users prefered language has a string matching the english one. This works like a charm, but has a long executing time. Is it possible to combine these 2 queries into one, and if yes... How?

Thanks in advance ;-)

######## EDIT

Tried this with no luck:

```
$res1 = "SELECT t1.text as etext, t2.text 
FROM ".$prefix."_language t1 LEFT JOIN ".$prefix."_language t2 ON t2.fk_id = t1.id AND lang = 'da'";
if($result1 = $mysqli->query($res1)){ 
    while($row1 = $result1->fetch_object()){
        $row1->text.'<br>';
    }
}
```

It doesn't reurn any result?

Comment: This won't be what's causing most of the long execution but only selecting the columns you need rather than everything `*` will save some time.

Comment: I think that your query is small and must not be slow!!! are you created any index for your table? there might be something wrong!

Comment: I have indexed lang, fk_id and still experincing an executing time well over 3 seconds?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.text as etext, t2.text 
FROM language t1 LEFT JOIN language t2 ON t2.fk_id=t1.id AND lang = '$language'
```

or something like this.
The main idea is to LEFT JOIN English part to another language part. It will return either 2 texts or only English one

Answer (score -1):

Well a solution using UNION and Sub-Query can works but may not be best bet if consider load time.

```
"( select text from ".$prefix."_language where lang = '$langid') 
union
( select text from ".$prefix."_language where lang = 'en' and fk_id not in ( select fk_id from ".$prefix."_language where lang = '$langid' ))";
```

Comment: Well down-vote is ok. But at least comment should be given, So answers can be improved.